# PHP How to header-location to a page in a parent directory?

Tags: php, header, directory, location

I have a `first.php` page with

```
header("Location: script/script1.php")
```

and `script1.php` has another

```
header("Location: first.php")
```

but it sends me obviously to `/script/first.php`.
Is there a way to redirect it to `<root>/first.php` instead of `<root>/script/first.php`?

Comment: Try header("Location: /first.php")

Comment: @Ziumin, Relative paths are not allowed in `Location` headers.

Comment: Yep, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-10.11 sorry

Answer (score 21, accepted):

have a try with this:

```
header("Location: ../first.php")
```

or use an absolute path or url instead.

Explanation: `..` is the unix/linux expression used for 'parent directory'. The Internet is unix land, so that rules applies there too.

Comment: Fair enough, I have removed my downvote.  I have not seen a browser where they don't work, but they are not allowed, I believe according to RFC2616.

Comment: @Brad: I just read that http/1.1 is to get a revision that defines relative location headers. I guess that is due to 'popular demand'... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: Indeed, they're useful for the same reason that relative URLs in otehr contexts are -- they allow you to write location-independent scripts and webpages that reference each other.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of: 
`header("Location: ../first.php")`

try with this:
 `header("url: ../first.php")`

this will change the url.Using location don't work in some cases

Since: `'../'` is to denote 'parent directory'.So,this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. Redirects back to the Home directory (Root) in '0' seconds -

```
<?php

     header('Refresh: 0, url = /Root_Dir/');

?>
```

Replace the 'Root_Dir' with your directory name.