# Header() and directory above

Tags: php, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP How to header-location to a page in a parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366217/php-how-to-header-location-to-a-page-in-a-parent-directory)

Function header() dont find directory above.

```
$link = "../hide/success-registr.phtml";
header("Location: $link");
```

Its path right and file exists.

Comment: Is that path inside the web server's document root? (note you should be using a full URL with domain and protocol in the `Location` header)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an absolute URL, for example:

```
$link = "http://www.mydomain.tld/public/success-registr.phtml";
header("Location: $link");
```

Note: The browser is going to request the provided URL, so using a 'hidden' page/response is not possible.

Comment: Most every browser will respect the relative url, even though it is an incorrect implementation.

Comment: You still shouldn't depend on error recovery though.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski probably as each browser tries to be as flexible as possible. But as you already indicate it is not something to blindly trust on, and is prone to result in 'unstable' behavior.

Comment: http://www.mydomain.tld/hide/success-registr.phtml not exists. Its other folder, not web server, i think.

Comment: @Quentin I didn't mean to say it's ok to use, just that it is not likely the source of error here.

Comment: @row248 Uhm... Oo You need to change it with the *actual* domain you want to redirect to... Also the `hidden` part in your relative file location suggests that it is not a public page, which is unreachable by the browser!

Comment: @Verger I dont understand what i must do. If i put this file into webserver folder anyone can print site.com/hide/success-registr.phtml and he will see this page.

Comment: Why does it matter that everyone can see your success page? And the name of that page is quite hard to guess, so I doubt it will be a problem.

Comment: @Veger Get what I want to do not possible?

Answer (score 0):

From php.net

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.

It is always recommended to use an absolute path (full uri) with header() Location.

Sometimes relative paths will work but certainly not going up a level in the directory structure unless you were to do some manipulation of the path before passing it as an argument.

Answer (score -3):

You can try

```
$link = realpath('../hide/success-registr.phtml');
$rootPath = 'some/root/path';

$link = str_replace($rootPath, 'http://', $link);
```

Comment: That's going to supply a filesystem path, which is probably different from the web server path.